# Node.js express routing POST Request empty body, using body-parser

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, express, post

I am having an issue where my post requests from a submission form are producing an empty body, no matter what body parser settings I use. My package.json dependencies are all up to date, and a previous app I made (with the deprecated app.use(bodyParser);) does this with no issues. I have been pouring over SO and various sites and trying every hack, but nothing seems to work.

Here's the relevant parts of my app.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

var routes = require('./routes/routes.js');

app.post('/checklogin',routes.post_checklogin);
```

Here's the route function that's called on post request:

```
var checkLogin = function(req,res) {
    console.log(req.body)
}
```

Here's the form I'm trying to get my form from, templated in pug:

```
form(action="/checklogin" method="post" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
    input(id="login-email" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="email")
    input(id="login-password" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="password")
    button(id="login-submit" class='btn btn-primary') Login
```

No matter what combination of enctype or body parser settings allow me to have anything but '{}' as the req.body. If anyone could point out what I imagine is a really stupid bug, I would be eternally grateful.

Also, I realize this is probably not the best way to handle logins, but this is just to get POST requests working in general throughout the app.

Comment: Can you include your routes.js file.  Do you have a full router defined in this?  if so, why are you calling app.post vs router.post.  Also your functions expression name doesn't appear to match what you are calling.

Comment: Hey there, I do in my routes.js. I have a full module.export defined. so that post_checklogin routes to checkLogin. I use the case difference to differentiate between app and routes for myself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a `body-parser` issue, you're missing the `name` attribute on your `input` elements.

Taken from [W3C specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#control-name):

> A successful control is "valid" for submission. Every successful
>   control has its control name paired with its current value as part of
>   the submitted form data set. A successful control must be defined
>   within a FORM element and must have a control name.

```
input(id="login-email" name="email" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="email")
input(id="login-password" name="password" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="password")
```

Comment: Thank you so much! this was it exactly. For anyone who runs into this, The name field is what the property is stored under in the req.body - ie, by changing the name to "email", there's now req.body.email.